# QNetworkRequest and automatic convertation of percent-encoded characters

Tags: blackberry-10, percent-encoding, qnetworkrequest

I'm trying to download the audio samples from Amazon with the help of QNetworkAccessManager+QNetworkRequest+QNetworkReply. I've got a big problem in processing the redirect from, for example, http://www.amazon.com/gp/dmusic/aws/sampleTrack.html?clientid=Shazam&ASIN=B00DJBQWAE to http://d28julafmv4ekl.cloudfront.net/64%2F30%2F239068457_S64.mp3?Expires=1380627695&Signature=BlaBlaBlaBla&Key-Pair-Id=BlaBlaBla 
(Note the percent-encoded path returned from the server). The problem is that when redirect target URL is passed to new QNetworkRequest and the request is sent via QNAM, the %2F characters are automatically converted to slashes. This seems to be correct behavior, BUT the server requires these slashes to remain encoded. Is there any way to disable this convertation?

Btw, QNetworkReply also has similar feature - it returns the redirect url with already converted %xx characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a percent encoding to this url. This way, the '%2F' will be encoded to '%252F' and the QNetworkRequest will encode it back to '%2F'.

With this method: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qurl.html#toPercentEncoding